# Why is the legend of my HighChart PieChart behaving irradically, when I update my series data?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a semi-circle donut piechart, which I have been successfully able to pass data to in runtime. Both the Legend, and the Tooltip has been working perfectly, and shown the correct data.

The tooltip has been showing both the amount, and a percentage value. The legend used to show an amount-value, but I was required to change it to percentages. I didn't expect that to be hard, but for some reason, the percentage value behaves very strangely. The first data in the series will always show the previous updated percentage. The others I can't even understand what are doing. They seem to be following a pattern of their previous value as well, but something seemingly related to the first data, seem to affect them. They do not even add up to a 100 percent.

I've been trying to figure out if there is some designated required order, or sequence to follow, when updating the series values, and the legend, but I can't figure it out. if I switch the `this.percentage.toFixed(1)` with `this.y` it works again, but then with amounts instead of percentages.

i have reproduced the error in a JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kuF3q/

For this example, I have used the `Math.random()` to simulate new data, like this:

```
    chart.series[0].data[0].update(Math.random());
chart.series[0].data[1].update(Math.random());
chart.series[0].data[2].update(Math.random());
chart.series[0].data[3].update(Math.random());
chart.series[0].data[4].update(Math.random());
chart.series[0].data[5].update(Math.random());
chart.series[0].data[6].update(Math.random());
```

Note the difference between the tooltip-values, and the legend values. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why your example is going wrong, but you can get it working by using chart.series.setData like this:

```
function newData(){    
     var newData = [Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random()];
     chart.series[0].setData(newData);    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QwLR7/

Note, setData redraws the chart by default. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData.

Comment: Both solutions are excellent. This one was just the first of two right answers. +1 to both! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is your `newData` function :

```
function newData(){
        chart.series[0].setData ( [3, 2, 4, 6, 12, 6, 5]);
        chart.redraw(true);
}
```

Here is a JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/S5q53/

With random value : http://jsfiddle.net/S5q53/1/